# Perl Script that should move through array with i=3 prints indicies that aren't x3

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics

I have these arrays of Sequences and I wrote this script to walk through each sequence three letters at a time (eg. {0,1,2}, {3,4,5},{6,7,8}) and print the index of where it first encounters a certian 3 letter combination (TAA,TAG,TGA). (EX. if sequence were CGTAGCCCCTAACCCC, then the script would skip over the TAG in the 2 position because its not in the correct frame of 3 and report the TAA in the 9 position). Therefore, I am only expecting indices in multiples of 3 in my results.

On most strings there is no problem, however every once in a while it will index at 4 or other non multiples of three. I was wondering if anyone more advanced than I can figure out why this may happen. I know this script is ugly and I am sorry for that, I am a biologist and  I mod it for whatever I am mining out of sequences at the time. I just can't figure out the bug.

Here are some sequences from my file. The 3rd line is the sequence that gives the strange result. Just for an example of what I am dealing with.

```
AGGTACGCGAGTCACCTTTCGTCTTCAATCTCGTTTGATCGAAGCTATTTGTCAAAAAGAGAGGATTTTTTTGCATCTCAATTATGATCATTCCTTAGGGTTTTCAGGGTTTTGGATTGTTGTTTTTGTTAACATTTATCTGATTCGTTTGTATTTGTGTGGCAGTCTAAAGTGGCATCAACAATGGCGTCTTTTATTATACATAAGCCAAAGGAGAGATCGCCTTTCACGAAAGCTGCTTTCAAAACGGTACCTTTAGTGATTCAGCATTTTTATCTGAAATATGTTTGTTGCATTATTGAATGATTCTGATGTGGTGTTGCTACCAACTTGTCTATGTTGGTTGATTTAGCTTGATAGCATCAAGGAGTTGGAACTGTTTATGTTGAAGCATCGAAAGGATTATGTTGATCTGCACCGGACTACAGAACAGGAAAAGGATAGTATTGAACAAGAAGTAAGTACTCTGAGCTAGGCTTGCCCGTAGTATATATCTGAACTCATGAAGTTACTGCGATAAATCTATGCTTGAGTTGAGATTGAACATATGGAACTATGGAATCATAAGAAATGTAGCAACTCATATTGAGATAACTCAGGAAGATTAATGTCTATTACTTTAGATAGCGAGGGAGTTAGTATATTGTGACACTGAGGAACTTGGATCTTGTATTCTTATACCTCTTGCAGTGTTTGATCGAGAACTATGTCTACTTATGTGTTGTGTAATATCATCAAACTCTCTCTCTCTCCCTCTTGCAGGTTGCTGCTTTTATTAAAGCTTGCAAAGAACAGATCGATATTCTCATAAACAGTATTAGAAATGAAGAAGCAAACTCCAAAGGATGGCTTGGCCTCCCCGCAGATAACTTCAATGCTGATTCTATAGCACACAAACATGGAGTGGTATGATATGCACCAATGTAGTAAGCCAACTTTGGTTTTTTTTTACTATGTTTTCTTTCAAAGTATCTAGATGTGTAGAAGTAATGGTAATTTTTTTTGTATGCAGGTTTTGATTCTGAGTGAGAAACTTCATTCAGTCACTGCCCAGTTTGATCAGCTTAGAGCTACTCGTTTCCAAGATATTATAAACAGAGCTATGCCGAGAAGAAAACCTAAGAGGGTCATAAAGGAAGCTACCCCAATTAATACAACTCTGGGAAATTCGGAGTCCATAGAACCGGATGAAATCCAGGCCCAACCTCGTAGATTACAACAACAACAACTTCTAGACGATGAAACACAAGCCCTTCAGGTAACAAGGCAAATATACATGATCTTCGAAAACTTGCATAAGTTTTGTAGTTATGCTAAATTTTGAAATTGATAATTTTTGCAGGTAGAGCTAAGTAATCTTTTAGATGGTGCTAGGCAGACAGAAACTAAGATGGTGGAGATGTCTGCATTAAACCACTTGATGGCAACTCATGTTCTGCAGCAAGCCCAACAGATAGAGTTTCTTTATGACCAGGTTAGGACTTATTAACTTCTCTAACGCTCTCATGTCAACACACTGTTTTGTTAGGCTTTCACTGTTCTTTACACTCCTTTGCTATCTCAAAGTTAAATTCGGATGCTTATTGTATTCAGAACTTTTCCTTGTCACATTCACCTAAATTAGGTATAGAGACGGGAAAGAAACTTTGTATTGGTCCAATTTTAATTGCTCTCCAATTTAGTGGTAGGAAATGGAACGGTTAATGTTTTTAGCTATGTAAAGTCTCTAAAACTCCATTTGAATGTGTCAATGACTCAATGCCATTCCCAATACTTTAGTTTATGGGGCTTTGCAGTTTTCCTACTCTGTAAACGTACAGCTTATGACTGACTTGGTGGCTCTCTTTATGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTCTTGAGGCCCTTTTTCTCACTCAGTTTGACACTAAATGCAGGCAGTTGAGGCAACAAAGAACGTGGAGCTTGGAAACAAAGAGCTTTCTCAAGCAATCCAACGAAACAGCAGCAGCAGAACCTTTCTCTTACTGTTTTTCTTCGTCCTTACTTTCTCCGTCTTGTTCTTGGATTGGTACAGTTAAaaaacc 
AGGTGATTGTTTTGTTATTATAAATCAAGATCAGTACATATATATTTTTGTTTTTCTTGGTTTCATATGTAATATTTTGGACTTTTGGTGTTTAGGTTTTTGACTTGGAAGAAAAGAACGTAATGGATGAGTCACTACACGAGGTGTATAAATTTTGCCTCACCGATGTTGATGAGAGAAGCAAGAAAGAGACATCAATGAAAGATGATTACATAGAACATAAGAAGTCTACTAGATTGTTGGCTGAAAATGCGAAGAAGTCCGGTCACAGTTTAGAAATATTAAGGCCGGAATCTAAACCTGAGACTGAAAAAGAGGTGATTTTATTTTCTTGTTATATAAAGATTCGTAGACATATATTTGGTTTTTCTTTGGTTTCATAATATTTTGGACTTATGTGTGTTTAGGTCAATGAAGAGGAAGAGAAGAGAGTAATGGATCCGGATGTGGATATTAGTTGTTATGAAGAGTCACCACACGAGGTGTATAAATTTAGCCTCACCGATTTCGAAGAAGAGATAATGGAAGATGATTACAGAGAAGATATGAAGTGTAGAATGTTGGATGATATAGTGAAGAATTCCGGTCACCGTGTAGAAATATCAAGGCCGGAATATTATAAACCTGAGATTGAAAAACAGGTTTTATTTTTTTGGTTATTTTGTGATTAAGATCAGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTGGTTTAATAATATTTGATCTTGTGTGTGTTTAGGTATATGAAAAGGAAGAGAAGAAAGTAATGGATCCGGATATCTATATTAGATCTTATGAAGAGTCACCAAACGAGGTGTATAAATTTAGCCTCACTGATTTGGAAGAAGAGATAATGGAAAATGACTCCATAGAAGGTGTGAAGTGTAGAATGTTGGATGAAATAATGAAGAAGTCCGGTCACCATTTAAAAATATCAAGGCCGGAATATAAACCTGAGATTGAAAAACAGGTTAGTTTTTAATAAAAAGATCACTAGATATTTTTTTTTATTTTTTTTTGTTTTTGGTTTCATAATATTTGACTTGTGGCATGTGTTTAGGTATATGAAGAGGAAGAGAAGAAAGTAATGGATCCAGATGTGGATATTAGATGTTATGAAGAGTCACCACACGAGGTGTCTAAATTTAGCCTCACCGATTTCGAAGAAGAGATAATGGAAGATGATTACATAGAAGCTTTGAAGTGTAGAATGTTGGATGATATATTGAAGAAGTCCGGTCACCGTTTAGAAATATCAAGGCGGCAATATAATAAACCTGAGATTGAAATACAGGTGATTTTTTTTTTTTATTATTGTTGTTATAGTAAGATCAGTAGATATATATCTTGGTTTCATAATATTTTGGACTTGTGTGTGTTTAGGTCAATGAAAAGGAAGAGAAGAAAGTAATCAATACGGATATGGATATTAGATATGATGATGAGTCACCAGAAGAGGTGGAGACATATTCTAGTCTCACGGATGATGAAGAAGAGAGAAGCAAGGAAGATACATCAATGGAAGATGTGAAGTGTAGAATGTTGGATTAAAAAACGACGAAGCTCGGCCACCTTTTAGGAATATCAAGGCCGGAATATAGACCTGAGATTGAAAAACAGGTGATTTTATTTTGTTGTTAATTGTATTAGTAAAGATCAGTAGATATATATTTGTTTTTGTTTTTCGGTTTCATAATATTTTGGACGCTTGTGTTTAGGTCAATGAAGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGTAATGGATATTAGATCTGCTGGTCAGTCACAAACACGAGGTGTACAAATTTAGCCTCACCGATATCAAAGAAGAGAGAAGCAATGAAGATACATCAATGGAAGATTGTTGCATAGAAGAGGCTCAAGTCGGAAAAGATCAAAGAGTCTTCAGATTCAGAGAAAGTAGTGAAGAGAAGAGAAAATCCTCATCATCACCATTATCACCACTAACAGAGTTTAGGGATATGGAGAGTTTGACGTATTACATGAGGCAAAAAGGGATGCATCGAAGAAGAAGAAGATCATCAACATCACCACATTGTTGCCATAATGTAGTATACAATGAGTTTAAAGTGACGAAGGAAGAAGAAGAGGAAGAAAGACAAAGATTAACAACCAAACGTGTTCATTCTAAGCTTCATGAATACGAACAATTTTTAACTCAGTTTAAAAAGAAGAAGGAAGAAGAAAACGAGAGACGAAGATTATCACCCAAAGACTTTGAGCCTACGCTTCCTGATTACGACCAAGTGATTACTCGCTTTAGAGTGCTGGAGAAGGAAGAAGAAGAAAGACGAAGATTAGCAACAAAACATGTTCATCCTAAGCTTCCTGATTACGACCAGATTGCTACTAAGTTTAAACTCCTGAAGGAGGTAGAAAAAGAAAGACGAAGATTATTAACCAAACACAGTTCATCCTAAgcttcc 
TGGTAATTTTTGCATCTTCAAAATGTTCTAAAATTTTGGCAAATGGTTTTGTTAAGTTCGAATTTTTGGTTATGATACAGTTTGAACGTTTTTCTTCATAGATTACAGTTTTAGCAAATGTGAATCATTAAAAGTGGAATAGTTGGTTTGAAAACAATTGTCAATTTCATTTTTTTTTTGGTTTTATGGTTAGGCGAGGAAAGCATTAAGAGCTTTGAAAGGTATAGTGAAGCTACAAGCATTAGTGAGAGGATACTTAGTAAGGAAACGCGCGGCCGCAATGTTGCAGAGCATACAAACTTTGATCAGAGTCCAAACCGCTATGCGATCAAAACGCATCAATCGCAGCCTCAACAAAGAGTACAACAACATGTTTCAACCTCGACAATCCTTTGTAAAGAACTATTCTCATTTCCATTGGCTCTCTTTTTTTCTTTAAGCCAAAACAAGACTTAAAGTGTGTCCTCTGTTTGTAGGATAAGTTTGATGAAGCAACGTTCGATGACAGAAGAACAAAGATTGTAGAGAAGGACGATAGATACATGAGAAGATCAAGTTCAAGATCAAGATCTAGACAAGTGCACAATGTTGTTTCAATGTCTGACTATGAAGGCGATTTTGTTTACAAAGGGAATGATTTGGAGTTGTGTTTCTCGGATGAGAAGTGGAAGTTTGCTACCGCGCAGAACACGCCGAGATTATTGCATCACCATTCTGCTAATAATCGCTATTATGTAATGCAGTCTCCAGCTAAGAGTGTTGGTGGAAAGGCTTTGTGTGACTATGAAAGCAGTGTGAGTACTCCTGGCTACATGGAGAAAACTAAGTCCTTTAAGGCAAAAGTGCGTTCACACAGCGCACCGCGCCAGCGATCTGAGAGGCAGAGGTTGTCGCTAGATGAAGTTATGGCCTCTAAGAGTAGCGTTAGCGGTGTGAGTATGTCGCATCAGCATCCACCACGCCATTCTTGTTCCTGTGATCCGCTTTAActtaac 
GAGTTAGTAAACAAAGTGTTCACATTTTAGTAAACATTGTTGTTCGTTAATCACGTAACGTTTTGTTTTTCCAGTTTACACTGAGCTCTGATGAGTATATAACGGAGGTGAATGGTTACTACAAAACTACGTTTTCGGGAGAAGTCATAACGTCGTTGACGTTCAAGACGAACAAAAGGACATATGGGACTTACGGAAATAAAACCAGTAGCTACTTTTCTGTTGCCGCACCCAAAGATAACCAGATTGTCGGTTTTCTTGGAAGTAGCAGCCATGCTCTCAACTCCATCGACGCTCATTTTGCCCCTGCTCCTCCTCCTGGTAGCACCGGAGCTAAGCCCGGTGCTAGTGGCATCGGAAGTGATTCTGGTAGCATTGGTAGTGCCGGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTGATGGCACCAGAGAAACCGAAAAAAACGCTGGTGGCTCAAAACCTAGTAGTGGTAGTGCCGGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTAGTGCTGTTGGCAACGGAGAAACCGAAAAAAATGCTGGTGGCTCAAAACCTAGCAGTGGTAGTGCTGGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTAGTGCTGGTGGCAACGGAGAAACCGAAAAAAACGTTGGTGGCTCAAAACCTAGCAGTGGTAAAGCCGGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTAATGCTGGTGGCAACGGAGGAACCGAAAAAAACGCTGGTGGCTCAAAATCTAGCAGTGGTAGTGCTCGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTAGTGCTGGTGGCAACGGAGAAACTGTTTCCAACATTGGAGATACGGAAAGTAACGCTGGTGGCTCGAAAAGTAATGATGGTGCTAACAATGGTGCTAGTGGCATTGAAAGTAATGCTGGTAGCACTGGAACTAACTTTGGTGCTGGTGGCACCGGGGGAATTGGAGATACGGAAAGTGATGCTGGTGGCTCCAAAACTAACTCTGGAAACGGCGGAACTAACGATGGTGCTAGTGGTATTGGAAGTAATGATGGTAGCACTGGAACTAACCCTGGTGCTGGTGGAGGAACAGATTCAAACATCGAAGGTACTGAAAATAACGTTGGTGGCAAGGAAACTAACCCTGGTGCTAGTGGCATTGGAAATAGTGATGGTAGCACTGGAACTAGCCCCGAAGGTACCGAAAGTAACGCTGACGGCACAAAAACTAACACGGGAGGCAAAGAATCTAACACCGGAAGTGAATCCAACACCAATTCTAGTCCACAAAAGTTGGAAGCACAAGGAGGCAATGGAGGAAATCAATGGGACGACGGAACCGATCATGATGGTGTGATGAAGATACATGTTGCAGTTGGTGGTCTAGGAATTGAGCAAATTAGATTTGATTATGTCAAGAACGGACAGTTGAAGGAAGGACCCTTCCACGGTGTCAAAGGAAGAGGTGGCACTTCAACGGTGCGTAAATTTTTATTATTATGGCTCAATTACGTTTTTCGAATAAGTGTTAATTCAAGATTATTGATCTTCATGATTCTGCAGATTGAGATTAGCCATCCGGACGAGTATCTTGTTTCCGTCGAGGGGTTGTACGACTCTTCCAATATCATTCAAGGAATCCAGTTTCAATCCAACAAACACACTTCTCAGTACTTTGGATATGAATATTATGGAGATGGTACACAATTTTCACTTCAAGTTAATGAAAAGAAGATCATTGGTTTCCATGGTTTTGCCGACTCACACCTTAATTCTCTTGGAGCTTATTTCGTTCCAATCTCATCCTCTTCTTCCTCCTTGACTCCTCCTCCCAACAAAGTTAAAGCTCAAGGAGGAAGTTATGGAGAAACATTTGACGATGGTGCTTTCGATCATGTAAGAAAGGTTTATGTTGGTCAAGGTGATTCTGGTGTAGCTTATGTCAAGTTCGATTATGAAAAAGACGGTAAAAAGGAGACACAAGAACATGGAAAAATGACATTGTCAGGAACAGAGGAGTTTGAGGTTGATTCAGACGATTACATAACATCAATGGAGGTTTATGTCGACAAAGTCTACGGTTATAAAAGCGAAATCGTCATTGCTCTTACCTTCAAGACCTTTAAGGGTGAAACTTCTCCACGTTTTGGAATAGAGACTGAGAATAAATATGAAGTTAAAGACGGTAAAGGAGGAAAACTTGCTGGTTTCCATGGAAAAGCTAGCGATGTTCTTTATGCTATTGGTGCTTATTTCATTCCAGCAGCAAATTAGagagtt 
ACGTATGTCTTAGTTACTACTATCATACTATATTACTATGTATTGGAAAACTTTTGGTTAGAACCTGTTGGGAGGAAAGGGTTTATGTTCTGGTTCATTTTACGTGTACTAAGTACTTATAATTAAGATTAAAAGAAACATTTACAGCTTCACCCTCTGGTCGATGTATGTGGGCTGTGGGCATGTGGCCAATCTCTGAAGCGTTAGGTAGAGCAAATATAGAGTTGAGAGTTGCTTAAGTTAGTGAACGTGAATGACTAAAAAGATATGTTGCATTTAAATCGTATTGGGCCTCATCCCATCTAAAATATAGTAGGTGTAGGCCTTTTAGGTTAATTTGAATAAAATCAACCTTTTTGTAAGCAACATCGACGATTGTCACATTTTTCTCATACACATAGGTGTAATCTAGCTTTGAATGTTTTCTCATACACATAGGTGTAATCACCGTAATTATCATTTGTGAAGATATATGTTTTACCAAGTGGTTTGTATTGTCCATATATACTTTACCACTTTCATATTAACATATAATGTTTTTGTAAGTATTATACCATAAAGGATTGGTTTCTTAATATTATTAACAAAACGCAAAAATTCTTTTAAACGCAGGCGATTCCAATCCACAGCGTTGCGGTTAGAGTAGGATCAACACAAAGAGTAGTGATGGAGATCATAATCACATTCGCATTGGTCTACACTGTTTACGCCACAGCCATTGACTCCAACAATGGCACTCTCGGAACCATCGCTCCACTTGCTATCAGACTCATCGTTGGTGCTAACATTCTTGCAGCCGGCCCATTCTCTGGTGGTCCAATGAACCCTGGACGTTCTTTTGGATCATCTCTTGCCGTTGGAAATTTTTCAGGACATTAGgtttat
```

and here is the script I am running:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

# A program to find the first inframe stop codon of non-spliced intron containing genes
print "ENTER THE FILENAME FOR DNA SEQUENCES:= ";
# Asks for Sequence file and if file does not exist prints error message
my $filename = <STDIN>;
#my $sequence;
my @sequence;
chomp $filename;
unless (open(DNAFILE, $filename) ) {
    print "Cannot open file \"$filename\"\n\n";
}
@sequence = <DNAFILE>;
close DNAFILE;
open (FILE, ">AtPTCindex.txt");
my $j;
my $i;
my $codon;
my $stopseq;
my $counter;
#Change $j<(375) to n=number of sequences
for ($j = 0; $j < @sequence; $j ++) {
    $counter = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < (length($sequence[$j]) - 2) && $counter < 1; $i += 3) {
        $codon = substr($sequence[$j], $i, 3);
        if ($codon =~ m/TAG|TGA|TAA/g) {
            # m added before /TAG... above
            $stopseq = substr($sequence[$j], $i, 9);
            my $result = index($sequence[$j], $stopseq);
            $counter = 1;
            #my $results = index($sequence[$j], $stopseq);
            print FILE "$result \n"; 
            #print FILE "$results $j \n";
        }
    }
    if ($counter == 0) {
        print FILE "\n"
    }
}
close FILE;
exit;
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please don't use _magic numbers_ in code. If 27991 is the number of elements in @sequence, use `for ($j=0; $j<@sequence; $j++)`. Now, do codons span (wrap around) sequence elements, or is one sequence element completely independent of the others? Is each element 3n letters long? Note that your regex **match** operator does not guarantee that the sequence starts on a 3n boundary, nor does the index call for the stop sequence.

Comment: Never EVER do this: `#use strict;`.  Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of every script.  no exceptions.

Comment: So each line in the array is an independent element, and each line is not necessarily 3n long. I'm not sure what you mean by wrap around, a codon cannot start on line 1 and end on line 2.

Comment: Sorry @Miller I don't know why use strict; was hashed out. Its not in my file it must have been a mistake when typing my question.

Comment: Thank you for fixing `use strict;`.  Btw, saying this _" I'm not looking to have the script streamlined, i know its ugly. I just can't figure out the bug."_ is likely to turn off a lot of experts.  Streamlining and fixing code is often the best (or only way) to find bugs.  Yes, it takes work, but there are lots of reasons why coding style is important, as it either reduces the chances of creating a bug or it helps you find it if one does crop up.  As things stand, your question is still unclear as you need to explain better what your code is trying to do and therefore where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Miller once again, I'm sorry. I wasn't trying to refuse help, i just trying to make it easier. I included a sample set of sequences from the set im using, with the sequence giving funny results included.

Comment: No worries mate, I'm just trying to help you with [`How do I ask a good question`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Sample data is a good start, but you also need to describe in detail what it is you're trying to do with this data, and what your expected result is.  You don't have to teach us Bioinformatics, but we have to understand what the code is trying to do if we have any hope of discovering where it's going wrong, or if there is a better method of accomplishing it.

Comment: @Miller I rewrote my question. I hope it makes more sense now, thank you very much for trying to help.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean by wrap around, a codon cannot start on line 1 and end on line 2." That's what I was asking. In other words, each line (element of @sequence) is independent of the others. Now, it could be partial (missing letters at beginning or end), or do you guarantee that the element starts at the beginning of a codon? Even if it is correctly aligned, how do you know two codons 'AGTAGC' isn't going to return a hit at index 2? You may need to first split up the element into groups of 3 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As threatened, the following is a cleaned up version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;

die "Usage: $0 Filename\n" if @ARGV != 1;

my $file = shift;

open my $infh, '<', $file;
open my $outfh, '>', 'AtPTCindex.txt';

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    chomp($line);

    my $result = '';

    for (my $i = 0; $i < (length($line) - 2); $i += 3) {
        my $codon = substr($line, $i, 3);
        if ($codon =~ m/TAG|TGA|TAA/) {
            # m added before /TAG... above
            my $stopseq = substr($line, $i, 9);
            $result = index($line, $stopseq);
            $result .= " ($i, $codon, $stopseq)";
            last;
        }
    }

    print "$result\n";
#   print $outfh "$result\n";
#   print $outfh "$result $.\n";
}

close $infh;
close $outfh;
```

For the 5 lines of data that you provided, the following is the output:

```
84 (84, TGA, TGATCATTC)
3 (3, TGA, TGATTGTTT)
3 (3, TAA, TAATTTTTG)
4 (27, TAG, TAGTAAACA)
123 (123, TAA, TAAGATTAA)
```

I believe your issue is with these lines:

```
my $stopseq = substr($line, $i, 9);
$result = index($line, $stopseq);
```

You're pulling a sequence from the `$line` at position `$i`, and then immediately doing an `index` for it.  In the case of 4 of 5 of those lines, it immediately finds the same value `$i`.  However, in the case of line 4, it finds a matching sequence earlier in the line.

If this isn't desired, you'll have to explain what your desired behavior actually is.  Perhaps, you just want `$i`?  Or are you looking for a matching stop sequence any point AFTER `$i`?  You'll have to specify what your actual logic wants to be.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is perfect and I love you. And it makes it way easier to just hash things out if I only want sequence etc. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach, unpacking it into groups of three instead of counting by indexes of three. I believe this script does what you want, and it looks a lot cleaner. It can also optionally take the filename as argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'a'; # dummy value
my $resultfile = 'AtPTCindex.txt';

# User may have passed filename as arguement
if (@ARGV) {    if (-e $ARGV[0]) { $filename = $ARGV[0] } }
unless (-e $filename)
{
        print "ENTER THE FILENAME FOR DNA SEQUENCES: ";
        chomp($filename = <STDIN>)
}

open DNA,"<$filename" or die "Couldn't open $filename for reading: $!\n";
my @sequence = <DNA> or die "Couldn't read $filename: $!\n";;
close DNA;

# Uncomment the below line if you're braver than me
if (-e $resultfile) { die "Cowardly refusing to write to existing file" }
if (-e $resultfile) { unlink $resultfile };

open RESULT,">>$resultfile" or die "Courdn't open$!\n";
foreach my $string (@sequence)
{
        # split into groups of 3
        my @groups = unpack "(A3)*", $string;

        # Search for the group you want
        for (my $groupnum = 0; $groupnum < @groups - 1; $groupnum++)
        {
                if ($groups[$groupnum] =~ m/(TAG|TGA|TAA)/g)
                {
                        print RESULT (($groupnum + 0) * 3) . "\n";
                        print "$1 (" . $1 . ( $groups[$groupnum + 1]) . ($groups[$groupnum + 2]) . ") at index " . (($groupnum + 0) * 3) . "\n";
                        last;
                }
        }
}
close RESULT;
```

Running the script on your sample data, it outputs:

```
TGA (TGATCATTC) at index 84
TGA (TGATTGTTT) at index 3
TAA (TAATTTTTG) at index 3
TAG (TAGTAAACA) at index 27
TAA (TAAGATTAA) at index 123
```

...as well as writes the raw index numbers to the file specified.